# OpenCV4Android 3.1.0 JavaCameraView FullScreen and Portrait

Tags: android, opencv

I am very new to OpenCV, trying it for the first time. I ran the Tutorial3[CameraControl](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/2.4/samples/android/tutorial-3-cameracontrol), camera preview was fine portrait and full screen, when I integrate the same code in my project, I somehow get the camera in landscape mode and its not full screen. I get it this question has been asked quite a few times, but none of the solutions were helpful. I want my application to open up org.opencv.JavaCameraView in full screen portrait mode. Could someone please help me?

Below is the activity:

```
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
    //        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        return inputFrame.rgba();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        List<String> effects = mOpenCvCameraView.getEffectList();

        if (effects == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Color effects are not supported by device!");
            return true;
        }

        mColorEffectsMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Color Effect");
        mEffectMenuItems = new MenuItem[effects.size()];

        int idx = 0;
        ListIterator<String> effectItr = effects.listIterator();
        while(effectItr.hasNext()) {
           String element = effectItr.next();
           mEffectMenuItems[idx] = mColorEffectsMenu.add(1, idx, Menu.NONE, element);
           idx++;
        }

        mResolutionMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Resolution");
        mResolutionList = mOpenCvCameraView.getResolutionList();
        mResolutionMenuItems = new MenuItem[mResolutionList.size()];

        ListIterator<Size> resolutionItr = mResolutionList.listIterator();
        idx = 0;
        while(resolutionItr.hasNext()) {
            Size element = resolutionItr.next();
            mResolutionMenuItems[idx] = mResolutionMenu.add(2, idx, Menu.NONE,
                    Integer.valueOf(element.width).toString() + "x" + Integer.valueOf(element.height).toString());
            idx++;
         }

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onOptionsItemSelected; selected item: " + item);
        if (item.getGroupId() == 1)
        {
            mOpenCvCameraView.setEffect((String) item.getTitle());
            Toast.makeText(this, mOpenCvCameraView.getEffect(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if (item.getGroupId() == 2)
        {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            Size resolution = mResolutionList.get(id);
            mOpenCvCameraView.setResolution(resolution);
            resolution = mOpenCvCameraView.getResolution();
            String caption = Integer.valueOf(resolution.width).toString() + "x" + Integer.valueOf(resolution.height).toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, caption, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return true;
    }
//
//    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
//    @Override
//    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
//        Log.i(TAG,"onTouch event");
//        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
//        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
//        String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
//                               "/sample_picture_" + currentDateandTime + ".jpg";
//        mOpenCvCameraView.takePicture(fileName);
//        Toast.makeText(this, fileName + " saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        return false;
//    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onTouch event");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
                "/sample_picture_" + currentDateandTime + ".jpg";
        mOpenCvCameraView.takePicture(fileName);
        Toast.makeText(this, fileName + " saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is the custom view that extends org.opencv.JavaCameraView.

```
    public class Tutorial3View extends JavaCameraView implements PictureCallback {

    private static final String TAG = "Sample::Tutorial3View";
    private String mPictureFileName;

    public Tutorial3View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public List<String> getEffectList() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedColorEffects();
    }

    public boolean isEffectSupported() {
        return (mCamera.getParameters().getColorEffect() != null);
    }

    public String getEffect() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getColorEffect();
    }

    public void setEffect(String effect) {
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setColorEffect(effect);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }

    public List<Size> getResolutionList() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    }

    public void setResolution(Size resolution) {
        disconnectCamera();
        mMaxHeight = resolution.height;
        mMaxWidth = resolution.width;
        connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public Size getResolution() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    }

    public void takePicture(final String fileName) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Taking picture");
        this.mPictureFileName = fileName;
        // Postview and jpeg are sent in the same buffers if the queue is not empty when performing a capture.
        // Clear up buffers to avoid mCamera.takePicture to be stuck because of a memory issue
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

        // PictureCallback is implemented by the current class
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving a bitmap to file");
        // The camera preview was automatically stopped. Start it again.
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);

        // Write the image in a file (in jpeg format)
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mPictureFileName);

            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();

        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: have you found answer for this, Javacamera view not taking fullscreen in potrait mode. @Akash

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45226234/6208255, i think you can get your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the AndroidManifest.xml in the sample, the orientation of the activity is `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

Comment: I know but, I don't want to do it forcefully. Thanks for suggestion though.