# OpenCV - How to set a Full Screen Camera view in Android?

Tags: java, android, opencv, camera, android-camera

**Background**

As a novice in software, I am currently aiming to format my camerapreview to full screen, that would be identical to the camera preview on Snapchat. Right now, I am able to showcase my camera preview in a 1:1 box format that I was able to set by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKvIKkBefJQ&ab_channel=CodingCafe). Other potential solutions that I had encountered in other questions either stretched/distorted the previewed image, or didn't launch the application altogether. How would I be able to do this while still maintaining portrait mode? Code provided below

Additional device specifications include the fact that the device I aim to launch the application on is a OnePlus Six, and its aspect ratio is 19:9. This is what the camera on my application currently looks like this.

[image: This is what the camera on my application currently looks like].

I want to eliminate the black borders above and below the preview and allow the camera to take up the entirety of the screen.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.cv;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2
{
    private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    JavaCameraView javaCameraView;
    Mat mRGBA, mRGBAT, dst;

    private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;


    BaseLoaderCallback baseLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(MainActivity.this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status)
        {
            if (status == BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS) {
                javaCameraView.enableView();
            } else {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
        }
    };

    static
    {
        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV is Configured or Connected successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV not Working or Loaded.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        javaCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.my_camera_view);



        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)  {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permissions granted");
            javaCameraView.setCameraPermissionGranted();
            javaCameraView.setCameraIndex(CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_BACK);
            javaCameraView.setVisibility(CameraBridgeViewBase.VISIBLE);
            javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission prompt");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }



    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height)
    {
        mRGBAT = new Mat();
        dst = new Mat();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped()
    {
        mRGBA.release();
    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
    {
        mRGBA = inputFrame.rgba();
        Core.transpose(mRGBA, mRGBAT);
        Core.flip(mRGBAT, mRGBAT, 1);
        Imgproc.resize(mRGBAT, dst, mRGBA.size());
        mRGBA.release();
        mRGBAT.release();
        return dst;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (javaCameraView != null)
        {
            javaCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (javaCameraView != null)
        {
            javaCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV is Configured or Connected successfully.");
            baseLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV not Working or Loaded.");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION, this, baseLoaderCallback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            // camera can be turned on
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            javaCameraView.setCameraPermissionGranted();
            javaCameraView.setCameraIndex(CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_FRONT);
            javaCameraView.setVisibility(CameraBridgeViewBase.VISIBLE);
            javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        } else {
            //camera will stay off
            Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
        android:id="@+id/my_camera_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cv">

    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**UPDATE**: I have come across solutions that aim to change orientation and/or eliminate the action bar. Applying `setMaxFrameSize()` does not work aside from stretching the resolution of the CameraPreview.
Another answer I have seen is `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);` which is no longer valid as `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` has been deprecated. If anyone can offer the slightest bit of solution as to how I can fix this, I would be eternally grateful.

**UPDATE 2**: I have attempted to modify `layout_height` in my `activity_main.xml` file, only to have it push the preview further down the screen, while it still retains it's 1:1 box format. Additionally, I have also considered implementing `javaCameraView.getLayoutParams().height=` in my MainActivity only to have it distort/stretch the camera preview and not achieve my intended desire.

Comment: android studio is just an IDE, the result you're trying to achieve won't be changed by the fact you're using android studio to develop it, so i've removed it from your question. like the `android-studio` tag says, it's best to use it when your question actually involves the IDE itself, if you feel like your question involves the IDE specifically, you're welcome to revert my changes :)

Comment: Thanks for your changes! I was unaware.

Comment: it's fine, it's a common mistake, unfortunately i can't help with your question though, but i'm sure you'll find an answer soon

Comment: I sure hope so! It's one of the last things I desperately want to know how to do before I move on to my next step!

Comment: to be honest I'm not sure I fully get what you are trying to display full screen. You refer to the Snapchat preview [which has no frame alteration] but then inside `onCameraFrame()` you transpose. What are the users supposed to see if they open your app? a snapchat view? or themselves rotated? I may be wrong but with the current code it looks like you pick a content [e.g. a face] e.g. in portrait mode and then later you ask opencv to transpose this content, i.e. to adapt an original portrait "capture" to a full landscape one, which is going to distort the input

Comment: @Antonino I apologize for any miscommunication in the initial post. I am merely trying to get the camera preview to display in full screen. So when the user opens the app, they see a snapchat view in portrait mode (of the device's back camera only). Right now, my main focus is mainly making the 1:1 box preview (visual example in the post) take up the entire screen, so without the black bars above and below the camera preview. I appreciate your response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

I'm leaving at the end the full solution for the `MainActivity` class - both for the back and front cameras - after the code explanations

---

**Full Details**

I joined a few answers on this website and modified `onCameraFrame()`. Now I can open the app in portrait mode, as the native Android camera or Snapchat view

This solution is really lightweight, I didn't change any OpenCV file as in other answers on this website [e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816166/rotate-camera-preview-to-portrait-android-opencv-camera)]. Depending on the `activeCamera` you want to use [i.e. back or front one] there is a little modification required inside `onCameraFrame()`, which I will list below

**Common base**

So I first followed the 4 steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45226234/4092588), exactly as they are presented there and they really put me on the right track. It is worth to notice that with these changes you will get immediately a good looking landscape view but as soon as you put your phone in a portrait position the upper and lower black bands will come back. Changing the line at step 3 into:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

didn't solve for me. Also, if you want to go full screen you need to remove the title bar and in order to do so I incorporated [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25365193/4092588) too. This means that you will need to modify also this line in the `AndroidManifest.xml` from the previous step 2

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
```

Since you initialize the camera in two places and you need to change it [the current snippet works with the front camera, you need the back one] you can clean-up the code and start defining the camera of interest so that you can modify the input source in one point only:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2
{
    ...
    // back camera
    int activeCamera = CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_BACK;
    // front camera
    // int activeCamera = CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_FRONT;
```

then pass it to a new `initializeCamera()` method

```
private void initializeCamera(JavaCameraView javaCameraView, int activeCamera){
    javaCameraView.setCameraPermissionGranted();
    javaCameraView.setCameraIndex(activeCamera);
    javaCameraView.setVisibility(CameraBridgeViewBase.VISIBLE);
    javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}
```

which you have to call as soon as Android detects that the user has given the `CAMERA` permission:

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Permissions granted");
        initializeCamera(javaCameraView, activeCamera);
```

and:

```
    if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            initializeCamera(javaCameraView, activeCamera);
```

Now it's the moment to distinguish between front and back camera

**Back camera**

In this case you won't need to manipulate the frames at all and the code goes as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height){
}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
{
    mRGBA = inputFrame.rgba();
    return mRGBA;
}
```

**Front camera**

In this case you need to slightly manipulate the frames flipping them, otherwise your portrait mode will show upside down

```
@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height)
{
    mRGBAT = new Mat();
} 

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
{
    mRGBA = inputFrame.rgba();
    // flipping to show portrait mode properly
    Core.flip(mRGBA, mRGBAT, 1);
    // releasing what's not anymore needed
    mRGBA.release();
    return mRGBAT;
}
```

Finally, be sure that the frame manipulations you add to your code are really required. Their processing time lowers performances and can even expose you to unrequired troubles. I didn't check accurately but I'm quite sure that transposing the matrices in your `onCameraFrame()` was the root cause for distortion

---

**MainActivity for back camera**

```
package com.change.package.name;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2
{
    private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    JavaCameraView javaCameraView;
    Mat mRGBA;
    private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    int activeCamera = CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_BACK;


    BaseLoaderCallback baseLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(MainActivity.this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status)
        {
            if (status == BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS) {
                javaCameraView.enableView();
            } else {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
        }
    };

    static
    {
        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV is Configured or Connected successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV not Working or Loaded.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        javaCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.my_camera_view);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permissions granted");
            initializeCamera(javaCameraView, activeCamera);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Troubles");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                initializeCamera(javaCameraView, activeCamera);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeCamera(JavaCameraView javaCameraView, int activeCamera){
        javaCameraView.setCameraPermissionGranted();
        javaCameraView.setCameraIndex(activeCamera);

        javaCameraView.setVisibility(CameraBridgeViewBase.VISIBLE);
        javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height)
    {
    
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped()
    {
        mRGBA.release();
    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
    {
        // code for the back camera
        mRGBA = inputFrame.rgba();
        return mRGBA;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }    

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (javaCameraView != null)
        {
            javaCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (javaCameraView != null)
        {
            javaCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }    

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV is Configured or Connected successfully.");
            baseLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV not Working or Loaded.");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION, this, baseLoaderCallback);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity for front camera**

```
package com.change.package.name;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2
{
    private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    JavaCameraView javaCameraView;
    Mat mRGBA, mRGBAT;
    private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    int activeCamera = CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_FRONT;


    BaseLoaderCallback baseLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(MainActivity.this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status)
        {
            if (status == BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS) {
                javaCameraView.enableView();
            } else {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
        }
    };

    static
    {
        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV is Configured or Connected successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV not Working or Loaded.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        javaCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.my_camera_view);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permissions granted");
            initializeCamera(javaCameraView, activeCamera);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Troubles");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                initializeCamera(javaCameraView, activeCamera);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeCamera(JavaCameraView javaCameraView, int activeCamera){
        javaCameraView.setCameraPermissionGranted();
        javaCameraView.setCameraIndex(activeCamera);   
        javaCameraView.setVisibility(CameraBridgeViewBase.VISIBLE);
        javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height)
    {
        mRGBAT = new Mat();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped()
    {
        mRGBA.release();
    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
    {
        // code for the front camera
        mRGBA = inputFrame.rgba();
        // flipping to show portrait mode properly
        Core.flip(mRGBA, mRGBAT, 1);
        mRGBA.release();
        return mRGBAT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }    

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (javaCameraView != null)
        {
            javaCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (javaCameraView != null)
        {
            javaCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }    

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV is Configured or Connected successfully.");
            baseLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV not Working or Loaded.");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION, this, baseLoaderCallback);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would I have to ```Pull method `initializeCamera' to 'CvCameraViewListener2``` in order to implement that new method? If so, it runs the error error: ```CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListenerAdapter is not abstract and does not override abstract method initializeCamera(JavaCameraView,int) in CvCameraViewListener2```. If not, then the Gradle Build will not launch. Also, ```requestCode``` and ```grantResults``` turn up red when typing them in, coming up as errors. Other than that, I very much appreciate your effort!

Comment: @RunMildew I'm not sure I understood your question but `initializeCamera()` can be added between `onRequestPermissionsResult()` and `onCameraViewStarted()`. Leave the declaration of `MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE` where it is now and add `int activeCamera = CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_BACK;` just below

Comment: Okay, so my question was a result of me putting ```@Override``` and trying to implement ````initializeCamera()``` that way. But seeing your response had prompted me to insert ```initializeCamera()``` right after the ```onCameraViewStarted()``` method since it can go anywhere in between ```OnCameraViewStarted()``` and ```onRequestPermissionsResult()```. So I've done everything... and it seems the only errors I have now is that ```requestCode``` and ```grantResults``` are the only ones that show up red. in Build Output, it reads ```cannot find symbol variable for requestCode and grantResults```

Comment: you already had `private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;` at the right place and visible [= no red sign]. You need to add `int activeCamera = CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_BACK;` just after. Check the parentheses in the MainActivity class, be sure that each method closes before a new one is declared

Comment: Just two more things, @Antonino . I have updated my AndroidManifest file in the original post to the steps you laid out for them. However, you will notice that the ```android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar``` does not have a ```.FullScreen``` at the end and this is because that addition in particular makes the entire line red. Aside from this, while the application has launched on my device, the camera preview has still retained its 1:1 box format while the view is rotated 90° counterclockwise. Do you think this might be because of the declarations in the AndroidManifest file?

Comment: Mate, adding `.FullScreen` should be doable. This is [my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I67QZ.png). I guess you are misplacing the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25365193/4092588) which must be inserted in `res/values/styles.xml` and NOT in the AndroidManifest.xml. If you notice the `style name` is exactly `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen`. The app works, I tested it

Comment: My friend, you are absolutely right! It works! Thank you for everything! If there's any way I can thank you in other ways, please let me know. By any chance, is there any way I'd be able to keep it full screen but still have the screen orientation in portrait? As in the phone's status bar being able to be pulled from the top? Thank you @Antonino

Comment: that's a consequence of having to put `"android:screenOrientation="landscape"`. As said if you change it to portrait it will not be anymore full screen. There is a [github thread](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4704) on this issue, you can try to see if the solutions posted there help. Or you can work around the problem, e.g.you can start the app with a landscape splash screen and the users will understand that the app has been thought to work by default with that orientation

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your **MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        try {
            Data = data;
            if(flag == true) {
                fheight = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;
                fwidth = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;
                flag = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm unable to implement the onPreviewFrame() method as it is greyed out. Any way to get around this? Additionally, even when manually inputting all of this, much of the code become red. Regardless, I greatly appreciate your response!